# get a plesk license from AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, centos, plesk

I have deployed a Plesk 'Bring Your Own License' AMI and now I need to get the license from AWS, how I do that without create a new AMI?, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Well "Bring Your Own License" (BYOL) means that you have to use your own Plesk license which you can install in Plesk UI.

You can [buy license](https://www.plesk.com/plans-pricing/) or take [one month trial](http://page.plesk.com/plesk-onyx-free-download) license on Plesk site.

Or you can use [non-BYOL Plesk images](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results?x=0&y=0&searchTerms=plesk%20onyx&page=1&ref_=nav_search_box).